# Update after a Copy Data Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I've got this doubt in Azure Data Factory. My pipeline has a copy data activity, and after loading the information in the table I need to update a field in that destination based on a parameter. It is a simple update, but given that we do not have a SQL task (present in SSIS) I do not what to use. Create a SP for this does not seem to be the most appropriate solution, besides, modify the database is complicated. I thought the option "Use Query" in the Lookup activity could be a solution, but this does not allow me to create a SQL query with a parameter, just like in a Source.

[image]

What could be a possible workaround?

Comment: Stored Procedure is exactly how I would handle this task.Why would you think it inappropriate?

Comment: It is a simple update and I can not modify the base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with the Lookup.  That is definitely the way to go. The query field there will allow you to create dynamic SQL just like you did within the copy activity.  You just need to reference the variable/parameter properly.

Also, with the Lookup, it will always expect something returned.  You don't have to do anything with that returned value.  Just ignore it, but the Lookup will not work without returning something. So, that query field would contain something like:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET IsComplete = 1 WHERE RunId = @{pipeline().parameters.runId};
SELECT 0 AS DummyValue; -- Necessary for Lookup to work
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @JeffRamos, thanks for your reply. But I wonder, if instead of a variable I need to use a Parameter, how could I change the query. I am new with ADF and sometimes for me this is a little bit difficult.

Comment: Instead of @{variables('runId')} you would just use something like @{pipeline().parameters.runId}

Comment: I updated the answer above with the code change for using a pipeline parameter instead.  I also included a screenshot demonstrating that this absolutely can be done easily, despite others saying it's not possible.

Comment: This is great JeffRamos!! Thanks a lot, I've got the result I was expecting. However I've got a question about this solution,  Is it always mandatory to write a parameter inside @{} when using it in a query?. I thought that just selecting it from the list could be enought,leaving it with the regular expression @pipeline().parameters.runID (without @{})

Comment: Glad you got it working.  The curly brackets are needed when you are doing some sort of string interpolation and the value of the parameter/variable is inserted into the body of a surrounding string. TBQH, the formats of the expressions used in ADF are kinda wonky and don't seem to be implemented consistently.  I still have to fiddle with it often to make it work.  And, I've definitely experienced the UI creating bad formats when clicking on values to add into the expression creation window.  It just takes a bit of trial and error, but you'll get there!